How Do I fix " Download is performed unsandboxed as root" error
So I was intalling WPS Office using sudo apt install ./wps-office_11.1.0.11723.XA_amd64.deb
after downloading the deb package, the WPS office is installed though but the terminal threw this error at the end:
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-mscorefonts-installer.
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/suraj/Downloads/wps-office_11.1.0.11723.XA_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Then I got another system notification, as "Update Information":
Failure to download extra data files

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.

What should I do?

N: means notification. That's not an error.

Failure to download extra data files is an actual error, but it's a network issue. Maybe it's at your end, maybe it's at Microsoft's end, maybe it's an an intermediate hop.
